# TalkBack differences on Nexus 4.4.2 and Samsung 4.1.2 when reading screen contents

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am seeing a difference between what TalkBack reads out loud when a screen is displayed on a Nexus 7 (4.4.2) and a Samsung SGH-I317 (4.1.2).

- On Samsung SGH-I317 (4.1.2) when a screen is displayed some elements
  are read out loud but not all of the elements displaued.
- On the Nexus 7 (4.4.2) TalkBack reads only those elements that are specifically
  selected/tapped.

Is this a Samsung/Nexus difference or an Android 4.1.2/4.4.2 difference?

What is the expected behaviour when a screen is displayed, should TalkBack read all the elements on the screen or just read what screen is displayed and leave it to users to touch a UI element before it is read out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 4.1.2 (early JellyBean) and 4.4.2 (KitKat) are significantly different versions of the Android OS and you should expect different behavior. Additionally, unless you have manually updated from the Play Store, the devices will be running significantly different versions of TalkBack.

Comment: OK thank you for your reply. I will compare the Talkback versions as well.